# How do I manage a stack of previous SearchView searches and access them via the Up button?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, android-support-library, droidquery

I am working on a simple application that uses [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery) to make network requests to fetch public stream data from a variety of websites. The requirements of the project include supporting *API 8*, and having an *ActionBar*. Instead of using *ActionBarSherlock*, I thought I would try my luck at the compatibility *ActionBar* in the *android-support-v7-appcompat* library. This has been working well for the most part, but I am having trouble handling the *Up* Button in order to navigate to previous searches (which search users on the public streams). Here is what I have:

> Note this is a stripped down version, and some methods are missing (although I have implemented them in my code).

```
public class PublicStreamClient extends ActionBarActivity implements OnQueryTextListener, OnSuggestionListener, OnPullToRefreshListener {
    private Stack<SearchStackItem> previousSearches;//initialized in onCreate
    private class SearchStackItem {
        public String query;
        public SearchStackItem(String query) {
            this.query = query;
        }
    }

    //called when the user searches a network with the given string
    public void search(final String query, final boolean addToStack) {
        //do search using given query String
        //once completed successfully, add the search to the stack:
        previousSearches.add(new SearchStackItem(query));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: {
                Log.d(TAG, "Home Pressed");//Never reached!
                if (!previousSearches.isEmpty()) {
                    SearchStackItem search = previousSearches.pop();
                    search(search.query, false);
                    return true;
                }           
                break;
            }
            default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.reddit_client, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search user name...");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
        searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        setSuggestionsEnabled(true);//sets up the suggestions cursor

        searchView.setQuery("", false);
        search(null, false);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

This is my menu `XML` that adds the `SearchView` to the Activity:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:rc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          rc:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          rc:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

This approach makes a lot of sense logically, however when I click the *Up* button, the `SearchView` just closes, and I never see the output "Home Pressed". What do I need to do to get this to work correctly? I am looking for an answer that uses the **compatibility ActionBar, not ActionBarSherlock**, and not native ActionBar for higher APIs.

---

Things I have tried include [Clicking app icon doesn't trigger onOptionsItemSelected()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953120/clicking-app-icon-doesnt-trigger-onoptionsitemselected) (following the comment in the answer regarding the support library), but this also did not do the trick.

I also stumbled upon the call `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true)`, which also had no results. On doing some tests, it seems like clicking the up button registers no callback to `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: Have you tried adding these:   `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
        `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: @btse, I just tried the second method, but it still did nothing. I also did some debugging and found that `onOptionsItemSelected` is not even registered when the home button is clicked.

Comment: that's odd. I use ABS instead of the compatability ActionBar...maybe it's a bug...idk

Comment: Are you doing anything in your `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: @btse, I added the relevant parts of `onCreateOptionsMenu` that initialize the `searchView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple mistake of not making the correct `Stack` calls.

```
previousSearches.add(new SearchStackItem(query));
```

Should have been

```
previousSearches.push(new SearchStackItem(query));
```