# How to make an icon in a style clickable?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a universal style for my sherlock actionbar set like so:

```
<style name="app_action_bar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo</item>
</style>
```

How do I make the logo clickable, and set an onclickhandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is a special application icon (android.R.id.home) details of handling on click are here:

[Clicking app icon doesn't trigger onOptionsItemSelected()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953120/clicking-app-icon-doesnt-trigger-onoptionsitemselected)